# What Makes a Maven Profile Not Appear in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-profiles

The profile I would like to add is: `INSTALL-KIT-GENERATION-AIX-POWER-64`.

I made sure to add it in the project's POM:

```
    <profile>
        <id>INSTALL-KIT-GENERATION-AIX-POWER-64</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                       .
                       .
                       .
```

However, I still don't see it in the list of the profiles in Intellij. Should I add it somewhere else?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the corresponding pom.xml is added as Maven project (in Maven tool window) and invoke Maven re-import in Maven tool window after you changed the pom.xml:

[image]